# Deleting Gazebo model causes Python to freeze

Tags: ros, gazebo7, service, rospy, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 with Gazebo 7.3 and Python 2.7

Whenever I call the Gazebo model deletion service, Python freezes.  No errors or special messages appear when the deletion code runs.  This happens whether I wait for the service to become available or not.  I checked that the model name is correct.

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import DeleteModel # For deleting models from the environment

def del_model( modelName ): # FIXME: Freezes Python, DO NOT USE!
    """ Remove the model with 'modelName' from the Gazebo scene """
    # delete_model : gazebo_msgs/DeleteModel
    del_model_prox = rospy.ServiceProxy('gazebo/delete_model', DeleteModel) # Handle to model spawner
    # rospy.wait_for_service('gazebo/delete_model') # Wait for the model loader to be ready 
    # FREEZES EITHER WAY
    del_model_prox(modelName) # Remove from Gazebo
```

There is no feedback from ROS / Gazebo as to what is happening.  Why does this happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241198/deleting-gazebo-model-causes-python-to-freeze/) by [jwatson_utah_edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/27605/jwatson_utah_edu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem. Make sure you are passing to the service a string.
use str(modelName) instead

---

Originally posted by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) with karma: 98 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1